# Binding derived class method in C++ to be called from separated std::function variable, outside the scope of the instance

Tags: c++

Consider having a base class that is inherited by multiple sub-classes.

Is it possible to bind some of its methods to create function that can be called directly and not from the inherited class instance.

The following example should emphasis the case :

```
class A {
    virtual void method(int a, int b) { ... } 
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void method(int a, int b) { ... }
};
class C : public A {
    virtual void method(int a, int b) { ... }
};


void main () {

    A * a = new B();
    A * aa= new C();

    std::function<void(int,int)> f1 = std::bind(&A::method, &a);
    std::function<void(int,int)> f2 = std::bind(&A::method, &aa);

    f(1,2); 
    f(2,3); 
    ...
}
```

however, it doesn't compile due to the following error :

`No viable conversion from '__bind<void (A::*)(int, int), A **>' to 'std::function<void (int, int)>'`

Perhaps anybody can help me fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

- You need to make the methods public
- `void main()` comes from a time of pre-standardization, it's not valid C++ code. You need `int main()`
- don't use raw pointers that have ownership. use smart pointers.
- don't use `std::bind`. Use lambdas. They are superior in every way.

---

In order to not overload you with all the changes, lets do this with lambdas and keep the raw pointers:

```
int main ()
{
    A * a = new B();
    A * aa= new C();

    std::function<void(int,int)> f1 = [=](int p1, int p2) { return a->method(p1, p2); };
    std::function<void(int,int)> f2 = [=](int p1, int p2) { return aa->method(p1, p2); };

    f1(1, 2);
    f2(2, 3);
}
```

And now a variant with smart pointers. If your `f1` and `f2` don't live beyond `a` and `aa` you can do this:

```
void test()
{
    std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<B>();
    std::unique_ptr<A> aa = std::make_unique<C>();

    std::function<void(int,int)> f1 = [ptr = a.get()](int p1, int p2) { return ptr->method(p1, p2); };
    std::function<void(int,int)> f2 = [ptr = aa.get()](int p1, int p2) { return ptr->method(p1, p2); };

    f1(1, 2);
    f2(2, 3);
}
```

Else you need to use `shared_ptr`:

```
void test_shared()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<B>();
    std::shared_ptr<A> aa = std::make_shared<C>();

    std::function<void(int,int)> f1 = [=](int p1, int p2) { return a->method(p1, p2); };
    std::function<void(int,int)> f2 = [=](int p1, int p2) { return aa->method(p1, p2); };

    f1(1, 2);
    f2(2, 3);
}
```

Also if you don't need the type erasure of `std::function` you should make `f1` and `f2` lambdas. E.g. `auto f1 = [=] ...`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use placeholders for your arguments. I would also remove the reference from the second argument as you've a pointer already and passing a reference to a pointer would pass in the address of pointer which is not what you want.

```
std::function<void(int,int)> f1 = std::bind(&A::method, a, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
```

Hope this helps.